# why is SlidingDrawer deprecated in API level 17

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I mean, it seems that SlidingDrawer is very convenient for users to use.So ,why is it deprecated by google? is there any reason? and,should I keep using it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html.

Comment: Why do you want to use SlidingDrawer? If you let me know then I can show you better options.

Comment: BTW deprecated means you can still use but its not advisable to use, instead you can use new features added.

Comment: @PareshMayani so what to use instead of the Sliding Drawer. I want a menu like sliding drawer which should slid from Bottom to top and vice versa. What is the better option ?

Comment: @QadirHussain how about using `PopupMenu`?

Comment: @PareshMayani I wanna use drawer,but the normal drawer needs you to push the button or swipe from the very left of the screen,it's not convenient.so I wanna use SlidingDrawer.